# Group policy preference power plan and console lock display timeout

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

I have set a default GPP power plan for the domain by creating a GPP power plan under Power Options, checking the default box, and setting the action to Create.

However, on Windows 10 devices, the console lock display timeout setting is set to the default (1 second? or whatever it is) on the device because I don't have [the option to configure it in the GPP as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUQ0f.png).

Is there a registry key I can set to turn the "console lock display timeout" setting off? Or some way I can enable it in GPP so I can set it via group policy management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting is not available in the Power Plan GPP.

However, you can change this value (videoconlock) by using the following command:

*for AC power:*

`powercfg.exe /setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEOCONLOCK <number of seconds>`

*for DC power:*

`powercfg.exe /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEOCONLOCK <number of seconds>`

I recommend creating an [Immediate Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd851779(v=ws.11)) via GPP to launch this command only once per computer, as SYSTEM account (for example).

you can find more information about the videoconlock settings here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2835052/monitor-powers-off-after-1-minute-when-pc-is-locked (the KB says Windows 8 but the content is still relevant for Windows 10)